# Execution time in Miracl library

Tags: c, performance

In the bmark program, the execution time is calculated as follow:

For example, for EC point multiplication:

```
#define MIN_TIME 10.0
#define MIN_ITERS 20 
start=clock();
do {
ecurve_mult();
iterations++;
elapsed=(clock()-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
} while (elapsed<MIN_TIME || iterations<MIN_ITERS);
elapsed=1000.0*elapsed/iterations;
printf("ER - %8d iterations",iterations);
printf(" %8.2lf ms per iteration\n",elapsed);
```

The question is: Why do not simply use:

```
start=clock();
ecurve_mult();
elapsed=(clock()-start)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%f\n",elapsed*1000.0);
```

In other words, what is the purpose of using MIN_TIME and MIN_ITERS

NB: the two codes give different outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is trying to execute `ecurv_mult()` enough times to make up for the lack of precision in the time measurement. So the loop makes sure it gets executed at least 20 times and for at least 10 seconds.

Since some machines might be so fast that executing 20 times is not enough time to get the accurate precision, on those we make sure to do it for at least 10 seconds regardless of how fast we did those 20 times.

If we do it only once, our performance measurement is not going to be very accurate due to the resolution of the clock being too high (e.g. the clock gives us 1ms while the benchmark runs in 500us).

Comment: Thank's Sasha, but what about the instruction : elapsed=1000.0*elapsed/iterations;

Comment: @zof So you multiplied a hopelessly imprecise sample size of 1 by 1000. Now you have a value whose reliability is equally tiny, but it's 1000x bigger. Still not useful! Do you realise multiple samples and averaging are needed to get any kind of useful estimates, because if you only run something once or any other small number of times, it's more vulnerable to being skewed by pure chance or unpredictable things like, I dunno, your computer deciding to run some background task at the same time? I highly recommend that you read up about some rudimentary statistical terms, primarily _sample size_.

Comment: ...I mean, that's kind of parallel to the clock resolution thing rightly pointed out by Sasha, but accounting for both are equally important to impart any usefulness to any benchmark.

Comment: @underscore_d So the instruction is used by the developer to reach the most accurate time ?

Comment: @zof Oh, I hadn't read fully and thought that was your instruction, used to multiply the result of 1 iteration by 1000 iterations, as if you'd get the same result. As I indicated, that wouldn't work, and all the _other_ stuff is for accuracy and is very important as I said. But this other bit is even simpler. Think about it. `elapsed` is time in seconds. `elapsed/iterations` gives you seconds per iteration. That `*1000` gives you milliseconds per iteration.

Comment: @underscore_d: this part (*1000) of the instruction is understood,

The doubt is in the last sample (elapsed) of the loop ! ... used in the instruction

Comment: @zof What next? The body of the `while` loop simply uses `elapsed` as a reusable sink to store the time difference between _now_ - _start of test_ in each iteration, to enable the condition of the `while` loop to then check `elapsed` and keep iterating until the `elapsed` time is at least `MIN_TIME`, i.e. the minimal duration that the test's author specified. Once the loop finishes, necessarily `elapsed` holds the final `elapsed` time for printing. It would really help if you'd think about the code more and perhaps draw a flowchart or something if you need to. IMO none of this is very complex.

Comment: @underscore_d: The elapsed used in (elapsed=1000.0*elapsed/iterations)

is the last value of elapsed from the loop

there, was the doubt, not in how to calculate !!

Please understand the question before replying

Comment: @zof So what is the question? You've just told me what I've just told you. Does that mean you're acknowledging my answer, or you're trying to ask a different question? It's not clear.

Comment: @underscore_d: The library's developer used this instruction: (elapsed=1000.0*elapsed/iterations)  WHY ?

Comment: @zof Don't shout at me. I'm doing this for free. I don't have to. You're welcome, btw. Anyway, either there's a language barrier, or I'm being made to repeat myself. So again, post-loop, `elapsed` holds duration in seconds from the test's start to the end of its last iteration after `MIN_TIME`. Then it's divided by count of `iterations` to get mean duration in seconds _per_ iteration. Then multiply by 1000 to convert to milliseconds. Then store back in `elapsed`. Why there, not a new variable? Well, it's an available slot that'd otherwise be unused afterwards. Want any more, ask the developer.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs the `ecurve_mult` function multiple times in order to get an average run time.

`MIN_ITERS` specifies the minimum number of times to run the function, while `MIN_TIME` specifies the minimum cumulative run time.

So in this case, the function has to run either 20 times or for a total of 10 seconds, whichever occurs first.

In contrast, the second code snippet only runs the code once.

BTW, the following is invalid:

```
printf(elapsed*1000.0);
```

It should be:

```
printf("%f\n",elapsed*1000.0);
```

Comment: Thank's dbush for the reply